# Textbox item not linked to a dataset

Tags: c#, aggregate-functions, reporting-services, rdlc

In the tablix if've got 2 fields (Quantity and Price) that is populated from the database (dataset fields) witch works great. Next to those two columns I added another column Total which I use to get the total of the quantity * Price

```
    =Fields!Quantity.Value*Fields!Price.Value
```

That works fine as well.
I then added a 3 textboxes at the bottom of that column (within a rectangle) which I want to use to do a Subtotal (sum of the Total), The vat and the the Grand Total after tax had been added. The problem is, is that I cannot add a dataset to a textbox, thus I cant use the Field Section when doing the expression which leaves me that I have to use the dataset section in expression to do this. This is how this looks in the dataset section: (and give me the following error:

```
    =Sum(Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "DataSetItemsRequested")*Sum(Fields!Price.Value, "DataSetItemsRequested"))
```

The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox53.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an aggregate function (or RunningValue or RowNumber functions) in the argument to another aggregate function (or RunningValue).  Aggregate functions cannot be nested inside other aggregate functions.

Is there a way that I can use a simple sum of that Total column or how do I add the dataset to the textbox or which is the correct way of how I can do this?

```
    =Sum(ReportItems!txtTotal.Value) doesn't work either....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just add a Footer row to the Tablix and just add the following expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value * Fields!Price.Value)
```

If you want this value outside the Tablix, you can use a similar expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value * Fields!Price.Value, "DataSet1")
```

Expressions in action:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `TextBox`, include your value in `Tablix`: insert another row inside/outside group and place your expression there.